# Scala Play - Json Parse

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework, null

I am receiving a JSON from an external service and my goal is to parse it exactly as it is.
The main issue is this: a value can be nullable or it can be absent BUT `null` has different meaning of absent. So I want to catch this somehow.
For example this JSON:

```
{
  "a": null,
  "b": 1
}
```

is different from this one:

```
{
  "b": 1
}
```

Can you help me please?

UPDATE:
Sorry for the delay in the update. Anyway: you are right, I have a implicit custom reads in the middle and currently I use `"a".readNullable[Double]` and `"a".write[Option[Double]]` and case class is something like:

```
case class Example(a: Option[Double])
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to catch this difference?

val json = Json.parse("""{"a": null, "b": 1}""")
is different from
val json = Json.parse("""{"b": 1}""")

Comment: Sorry, probably I forgot to add an important pieces so. I have an implicit read (readNullable) and an implicit write (writeNullable).

Comment: Right... so you have a case class like this `case class Yolo(a: Option[Int], b: Int)`?

Comment: Have a look here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Path-Reads

it says to use readNullable for paths that might be missing or be null

Comment: As @mfirry mentioned, `Json.parse` already captures the difference. If you are having a problem later in the process (as[...] or validate[..] maybe?) please post the actual code that is giving you problems.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just updated my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just laying out what @mfirry was talking about with a detailed example (play-json 2.6):

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val json1 = Json.parse("""{"a": null, "b": 1}""")
json1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"a":null,"b":1}

scala> val json2 = Json.parse("""{"b": 1}""")
json2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"b":1}

scala> (json1 \ "a").isDefined
res8: Boolean = true

scala> (json1 \ "a") == JsDefined(JsNull)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> (json2 \ "a").isDefined
res7: Boolean = false

scala> (json2 \ "a")
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult = JsUndefined('a' is undefined on object: {"b":1})
```